# how to configure listenerhttp processor in NIFI

Tags: apache-nifi

i'm using nifi with our web app ...we want to configure listenhttp processor that listen our web service. question is what are the configuration in http listener processor in nifi such that when we will make curl post request this ListenHttp processor will catch the update. basically i didn't understand what i have to put in Base path(is it i have to put nifi add i.e http://localhost:8080/contentListener or our web app service URL???) what is contentListener. And is it i have to put our web app port number in listening port? 
in the request command what i have to put in url part

```
curl --request POST 'http://(here i have to used the nifi url)' -H 'Authorization: Key demo-key
```

[image: didn't understand what i have to put in all field in this processor]

i know this is very basic question but i'm just using this don't know any thing about nifi and curl command .....thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

The `ListenHTTP` processor starts an internal web server and allows incoming connections (i.e. some other entity making an HTTP request to this address). It does not monitor an external HTTP resource and notify on changes. For this, you may want an `InvokeHTTP` processor which performs a `GET` request against your other service and processes the response, detecting changes via your logic (absence/presence of specific values, etc.).

#### Additional information

The "Base Path" value is the path for this specific listener. If you had multiple `ListenHTTP` processors, you would want to differentiate them. The default value is `contentListener`, which would result in external services needing to connect to `http://nifi.service:9999/contentListener`. The port is specified by "Listening Port". To enable TLS, configure and reference an `SSLContextService` in the "SSL Context Service" property.

The `ListenHTTP` processor does not provide token-based authentication, so if you want to provide a key in the "Authorization" header, you will need to put custom logic in subsequent processors to evaluate the presence and value of that header.